# JSON schema validation Draft 7 two type of data for one field

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema

I need help creating a JSON schema for a value that could be an object, or an array of objects.

- lib: jsonschema==3.2.0
- py: 3.8

I have 2 responses from the server:

first:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "brand": "Test"
    }
]}
```

second:

```
{
"result": 
    {
        "brand": "Test"
    }
}
```

As you can see the difference between both in the first case its an array of obj the second just object.

my schema:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
"$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
"type": "object",
"required": [
    "result"
],
"properties": {
    "result": {
        "$id": "#/properties/result",
        "type": ["array", "object"],
        "additionalItems": true,
        "items": {
            "$id": "#/properties/result/items",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "$id": "#/properties/result/items/anyOf/0",
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [
                        "brand"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "brand": {
                            "$id": "#/properties/result/items/anyOf/0/properties/brand",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"additionalProperties": true}
```

In the first case when return array, it checks the "brand" type on the second when return object, no.

How I can set up 2 types for one field "result" that it could check the brand type?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema can be fixed as follows:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "$id": "#/properties/result",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$id": "#/properties/result/items/brand",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "brand": {
              "$id": "#/properties/result/items/anyOf/0/properties/brand",
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "brand"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": true
        },
        {
          "$id": "#/properties/result/items/array",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/properties/result/items/brand"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Demos [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/m2vHwolz), [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/BtDVoo9R) and [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/YJxYU82h).

However, it is customary to extract reusable portions of a schema into a separate [`"definitions"`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html) section, like so:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "definitions": {
    "brand": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "brand": {
          "$id": "#/properties/result/items/anyOf/0/properties/brand",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "brand"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": true
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "result"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "$id": "#/properties/result",
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/brand"
        },
        {
          "$id": "#/properties/result/items/array",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/brand"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Demos [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/OwCbBgc2), [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/x6f5DLVk) and [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/BrqYYbmE).

Notes:

1. To express that the property `"result"` may be of two different types, use the [`"anyof"`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof) keyword for the property's schema.  The value of the `"anyOf"` should be an array with the schemas for each possible type (here the `"brand"` object or an array of `"brand"` objects) as the array items.

   See: [Multiple Types](https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/multiple_types/).
2. To avoid duplicating the definitions for the `"brand"` object, you can use the [`"$ref"`](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html?highlight=ref#id4) when defining a schema for the array's items to refer back to the previously given schema for `"brand"`.  As noted above it s customary to place reused subschemas into a `"definitions"` section, but it is not necessary, `"$ref"` can refer to any schema item via the [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) syntax.

   See: [Reuse](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#id1).
3. When the items of a list have a single schema, `"additionalItems"` should not be used.

   See: [List validation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#list-validation).